# Convert shell script to Windows command line or PowerShell

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, batch-file

I have a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ "Initializing handler" ]]; then
        cd /path/to/myapp/Client && /path/to/myapp/Client/jre/bin/java -jar Client.jar
        break
    fi
done < <(cd /path/to/myapp/Server && /path/to/myapp/Server/jre/bin/java -jar Server.jar)
```

This script starts a Java server application, then reads the lines that appear on the console output, and if the current/last line contains the text `Initializing handler` then it starts the client application as well. I want to convet this script to Windows command line or PowerShell. Is it possible to do that in Windows?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question seems to be asking the community to port the script, and shows no initial porting attempt. The question should at least be edited with OP's initial attempts to port this to Powershell, or else this is really off-topic for this community.

Comment: Well, I was only asking that is it possible or not.

Comment: If someone just writes yes as an answer, are you going to mark their answer as accepted, give them points for it, and be happy that future visitors to your question will find it of use?

Comment: I will also accept no as an answer if it answers why it cannot be done.

Comment: Well that would be two questions, your is 'can it?', not 'can it? and how?' So does than mean you will only accept `yes` as an answer? because `no` requires that we also answer another question not asked! *Also you didn't divulge whether you were happy that future visitors would find it of use.*

Comment: So the question then becomes: What will you do with the yes or no answer once you get a yes or no answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, it can be done.
Powershell has the ability to process stdin, and launch external commands.